# What word has the same flavor but opposite meaning of hence (in the future)

Tags: antonyms

My brain is claiming there is such a word, but Google seems to disagree:

Is there any word with the same "flavor" as `hence` (somewhat ostentatious, perhaps? Victorian?) in the meaning of "in the future", but with the opposite meaning. I want to say something happened two decades hence (meaning two decades ago), but I know it's wrong (it would actually mean two decades from now).

I've found `hitherto`, `heretofore` and perhaps `yet`, which have the "flavor" I'm seeking and the generally opposite meaning, but they don't seem to have the same idea of "number of years or amount of time" before now that `hence` allows for...

[edit] It would fit into a sentence similar to or along these lines:

> "Born forty-eight years [hence?], the gentleman accomplished several feats of note"

[/end edit]

Is there such a word?

Comment: All I can think of is *ago*, *gone*, *past*, *since*, etc. The word *hence* has some siblings: *whence*, *thence*, etc, but none of them have the sought meaning.

Comment: "ago" is the literally best word for this, but "since" seems like the closest relative of "hence".  I think if you add an example sentence it would help.

Comment: Maybe something like "lo these twenty years"?

Comment: Dan Bron's *two decades **past*** has a similar flavour.

Comment: 2 decades prior?

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I suppose the "something happened two decades _hence_" isn't a full sentence - this would be an event that happened and led to or enabled events since, like a birth or the significant change of life goals - something along these lines: "Born forty-eight years [hence?], the gentleman accomplished several feats of note"

Comment: @CodeJockey Can you edit your question to include the example (and make it a bit clearer that it is an example)?  Things get a bit lost in comments.

Comment: Must it be one word? "Ere now" has the right timbre to my ear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan Bron's suggestion of *past* has the right flavour. Here's an example in a book title (emphasis mine):

> For *Ten Years Past* I have Constantly Wished to Turn My Western Lands into Money: Speculator Frustration and Settlers’ Bargaining Power in Ohio’s Virginia Military District, 1795–1810
>   [- Hanno Scheerer](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/571707)

The primary drawback with *past* in this example is that it has the connotation of the duration of that interval, while *hence* refers more directly to the time at the end of the interval.

If we are permitted an unspecified but recent interval, another term with a similar flavour to consider is *late*.

> **Late** *adverb*
>    12. recently but no longer: *a man late of Chicago, now living in Philadelphia.*
>   [- dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/late)

One might extend this to say *late of Chicago, now living in Philadelphia, then on to Canada, two years hence.*

Another word to consider is *previous*. Unlike *past*, it refers to a specific time (not the interval), and unlike *late*, it can refer to a time of any duration before the present. Here's an example (emphasis mine):

> Struggling in the same job he received *twenty years previous*, Diddlebock is fired so he wanders the streets and eventually goes into a bar.
>   [- k-otic](https://archive.org/details/harolddiddlebock)

As for flavour, this is getting into personal tastes. Here's a sample for comparison and contrast with *hence*: *ten years previous and ten years hence*.

Comment: yes - I remember skipping past _late_ or _of late_ as well, due to having a "recent" connotation. I am ideally looking for something that was a fairly long time in the past, and happened once, not the entire duration, but I may have to settle with one slight inaccuracy or else abandon my attempt at that flavor

Comment: @CodeJockey I've added *previous*. It has some of the right qualities, though you'll need to judge for yourself regarding flavour :) .

Comment: I think I like _previous_ well enough - pretty close, though I really thought there was something even closer - idunno - thanks!

Comment: @CodeJockey It's an interesting theme, hunting for matching flavours to words.

Comment: Here's one more: [prior](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=XTxEAAAAQBAJ&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=%22twenty+years+prior%22&source=bl&ots=kPfqEuj6kL&sig=Y4qMkISPVntYT18T54j3GX_4jrE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH2OOXwpnMAhWDopQKHWtACJw4ChDoAQgoMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22twenty%20years%20prior%22&f=false). If you like this better, I'll edit it into my answer. (Edit, cut/pasted into a separate comment - SGR already suggested this in comments to your question. I'll delete this comment later.)